# Using powershell “switch -regex -file”, how get 'not matched' string on default block?

Tags: regex, powershell, switch-statement

i'm using a function to parse one ini file. I'm using `switch -regex -file` code to get matched lines with different RegEx expressions. But now, i want to to catch lines that not match any of regex expressions..

At this time, i can catch them with a default block, but i don't know how to show the line  contents, because $matches[1] is null (Commented line: `#$line=$matches[1]`)

**¿How can i get matching line on default block?**

**Note:** A possible solution it's to change default block by a block matching any line "^(.*)$", but i have curiosity about if they are any method to get 'not matched' strings on default blocks

**Thanks**

```
function CheckIniFile ($filePath)
{
    switch -regex -file $FilePath 
    { 
        "^\[(.+)\]$" # Section 
        { 
            $section = $matches[1] 
            Write-Host "Section: $section"
            continue
        } 
        default
        {
            # Next line causes NullArray error
            $line=$matches[1]
            Write-Host "No section: $line"
            continue
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the automatic variable `$_`, the current object in the `switch` loop:

```
    switch -regex -file $FilePath 
    {
        ...

        default
        {
            Write-Host "No section: $_"
            continue
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I'm begining with powershell and sometimes it's hard :)